# How to creat an online multiplayer game using flash or flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I want to know if there is any way to creat an online multiplayer game using flash or flex (flash builder) ... if we can, can you send me some tutorial in an answer
Thenx BeForE

Comment: The answer is "yes, you can", but that's an amazingly broad question.  Which part of the game-creation are you looking for help with?  The networking?  The game creation?  Finding a developer to do it?

Comment: Maybe you should try asking here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . Also you can't create a mmo game with only frontend technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with creating a multiplayer game is sending the data from one user to another. Recently flash has integrated a p2p protocol allowing for direct connections between users. This makes it relatively simple to send data between users. I suggest starting with a turn-based game because then you won't have any problems keeping the game state the same on both ends.

You can watch this tutorial which helped me out a lot:
http://www.flashrealtime.com/basics-of-p2p-in-flash/

Comment: Thenx dude you helped me a lot

Comment: +1; this is a great answer to a difficult question.